# Android application API calling error when using gson

Tags: java, android, gson

Hello I am calling API on my payment success event and send data on our server via API and it was working before but suddenly stop working below is my **error** and **code**

**Error**

```
failjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $
```

**Code**

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
        OkHttpClient.Builder okClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Base_url.url)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
```

Comment: Maybe server-side response changed so maybe you need to change the model class according to server response.
Please check server-side response and your model classes.

Comment: @ Nilesh Panchal this error is from onFailure so it can not be error on response

Comment: have you checked in postman that API is working properly in it?